# How do I use the form_for f.select builder properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a form, and I cannot seem to figure out how to use the f.select form tag properly, I just want to make your basic:

```
<select name='whatever[whatever]'>
    <option value='blah'>Blah</option>
    <option value='blah2'>Blah2</option>
</select>
```

Also how would I set classes on them and what not, Thanks!

Tried googling a bunch of things,

```
'How to use the form_for f.select builder properly'
'Rails 3 use f.select properly'
'Rails 3 add class to f.select'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have something like this

```
<%= select(:person, :city_id, [['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...]) %>
```

## controller:

```
@person = Person.new(:city_id => 2)
```

Notice that the third parameter, the options array, is the same kind of argument you pass to options_for_select. One advantage here is that you don’t have to worry about pre-selecting the correct city if the user already has one — Rails will do this for you by reading from the @person.city_id attribute.

As with other helpers, if you were to use the select helper on a form builder scoped to the @person object, the syntax would be:

## select on a form builder

```
<%= f.select(:city_id, ...) %>
```

I think this might be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Blog post on the subject here giving a couple of examples

http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/rails/using-collection_select-in-rails/